# stdatomic (C11), three questions about _Atomic types

Tags: c, types, atomic, c11

### First question

I found on cppreference

- `_Atomic ( type-name )`   (since C11)

  Use as a type specifier; this designates a new atomic type
- `_Atomic type-name`   (2) (since C11)

  Use as a type qualifier; this designates the atomic version of type-name. In this role, it may be mixed with const, volatile, and restrict), although unlike other qualifiers, the atomic version of type-name may have a different size, alignment, and object representation.

So does using `_Atomic(int)` instead of `_Atomic int` 
 guarantee it to be the same size as `int` or not?

### Second question

Using a qualifier inside `_Atomic`
Ex:

```
_Atomic(volatile int)
```

Throws an error, but using it like this:

```
_Atomic(volatile _Atomic(int)*)
```

Does not; is this standard behaviour?

### Last question

I noticed atomic functions (ex: `atomic_store`, `atomic_load`, `atomic_compare_exchange_weak`) work without the passed types being `_Atomic` types, and I can still manage race conditions with no problem.
Is this standard behaviour? Does it have downsides or lead to any error?

Comment: What do you mean by "I noticed atomic functions (ex: atomic_store, atomic_load, atomic_compare_exchange_weak) work without the passed types being _Atomic types"? According to C11 draft for example [`atomic_load()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.7.2) expects a single argument that is a pointer to atomic type.

Comment: "throws an error" - what error does it throw?!

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I'm passing any kind of pointer to it, still working as it should

Comment: In C a lot of times things might seem to work, until they don't, if you invoke UB.

Comment: Please don't ask several questions at once, really. This makes useful searching much more difficult. You could even split it up, now, given them useful question titles, and answer them yourself with what you now know from Antti's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First question:

[C11 7.17.6p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.6p3):

> NOTE The representation of atomic integer types **need not** have the same size as their corresponding regular types. They **should** have the same size whenever possible, as it eases effort required to port existing code.

Second question:

[C11 6.7.2.4p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.4p3):

> **[Constraints]**
>
> 3 The type name in an atomic type specifier **shall not refer to** an array type, a function type, an atomic type, or **a qualified type.**

`volatile int` is a qualified type. A **shall** in a constraints section is violated, therefore the compiler needs to output a diagnostics message. Beyond that, the behaviour of such a construct is undefined.

Third question:

[C11 7.17.1.p5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.1p5):

> 5 In the following synopses:
>
> - **An `A` refers to one of the atomic types.**

They expect an `_Atomic` type. You pass in a non-atomic variable, therefore undefined behaviour.